# How was the recursive fibonacci function derived?

Tags: python, fibonacci

In python, a recursive function for a Fibonacci sequence that returns the nth fibonacci number can be written as:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

I understand how this function works, but if someone were to have never seen this function before, how would one derive it?

Thanks

Comment: That first statement should probably be `if n <= 1` so the function is a bit more robust and doesn't go into infinite recursion for numbers <= 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a crude translation of the mathematical definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

The Fibonacci sequence is defined as:

> F<sub>0</sub> = 0
>
> F<sub>1</sub> = 1
>
> F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub>

You can see that the Python code is basically a direct translation of this (except with `n` off by 1).